# Is it possible to load ads of Admob in starting of app?

Tags: android, admob

Is it possible to load ads of Ad mob in starting of app and then use it in any button of whole project?

After click of any button it open quickly on every type of internet mainly on 2g 
without taking time to load

Answer (score 0):

it not a recommended way to show ads at start of the application as it result in poor user experience, like user might be interacting with your app and suddenly Ad pops up.

well if you still want to you can display it by overriding `onAdLoad` listener in your Activity's `onCreate`

```
mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitialAd_id));
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
            }
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE:**

With this method it will only display it if its loaded

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
    mInterstitialAd.show();
   }
```

Comment: i respect your suggestion but i already know all these things. Please read the query again, i want to load ads previously, don't want to show them at the same time. i want to use them only on some button clicks. but i can't understand how can i load ads previously?

Comment: you can always load ads in `onCreate` of you Activity with above mehtod and show them whenever you want

Comment: i am doing same thing but on 2G network when i click on any selected button it takes time of loading.

Comment: you can check the ad is loaded and available before displaying it, let me update the answer